# How to handle parent Activity when child Activity finishes

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities, say `LoginActivity` which contains a login UI and `HomeActivity`. On `HomeActivity`, I have put a button that calls the method below:

```
public void goToLoginPage(View view) {
    finish();
    super.finish();     
    Intent i = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

But when I click this button, the login page with the last entered credentials appears once again. Instead I want a fresh login page or at least without last entered credentials.

Comment: A guess based on the few details you're giving: you would need to modify LoginActivity's initialization.

Comment: Try by removing finish() and super.finish() in second activity button click

Comment: What is the starting activity (the one that runs when you launch the application the first time?

Comment: @DavidWasser:StartActivity is the LoginActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your information, LoginActivty is the starting activity and that activity, after a successful login, starts the HomePageActivity. To return to the LoginActivity, you can execute the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

This will only work if, when LoginActivity launched HomePageActivity, it did not call finish() on itself (ie: the instance of LoginActivity must still be present in the activity stack). Also, the launchMode of LoginActivity must be either default (ie: not specified at all) or "standard".

This will result in the current instance of LoginActivity being finished and a new instance of LoginActivity will be created and the onCreate() method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

on a successful login while you want to open the next activity, then finish() the login activity. By doing this, next time if you start login using intent it will open a fresh login page

Answer (score 0):

Call finish() method in LoginActivity when you start HomeActivity, that will make LoginActivity be destroyed. When you call startActivity to start LoginActivity, LoginActivity will instance a new one.

I am new in android develop, hopes that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

write following code in OnPause() of LoginActivity

```
protected void onPause()
{
super.onPause();
username.settext("");
password.settext("");
}
```

Comment: If you do this, everytime the user enters something in the login field, then presses HOME or takes an incoming phone call, when he returns to the app the fields will be empty. Not a good user-experience IMHO.